# Angular-CLI for visual studio

Tags: angular

Following the [steps to create HeroEditor as given on angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt1.html) , How to open it in Visual Studio?

I created an empty project and added Angular-CLI created files . Got multiple build errors on promise and set.

Comment: Wich version of Visual Studio? In 2017, you can create a nodejs website project. In 2015, you can do the same thing but you have to install the nodejs extension for Visual Studio. Then you can't run the project using the start button. You have to use the node js console (something like ".npm [myproject start]")

Comment: You can also run your project using the NPM extension for Visual Studio. It is what you are searching for?

Comment: Basically , Im looking to develop the above sample application using Visual Studio. Im new to Angular.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Visual Studio Code. Because you can use it as Angular Studio with extensions.

- Create project with angular-cli
- Open VS Code and show project folder

And here are the list of extensions may help you while developing angular apps

- [Angular Language Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template)
- [vscode-icons](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robertohuertasm.vscode-icons)

Comment: +1 for recommending a lighter (and free!) alternative to Visual Studio. I myself use Sublime, but only because I did not know about VC Code before. Strongly suggest the OP to try it!

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the same problem few days back and come up with the few solutions :-

1. If you want to use Visual studio 2017, there is a Project template available online i.e. Angular CLI Application ( New Project --> Online --> Search Angular CLI Application).
2. If you have only front end to develop go with the Visual Studio Code (recommended).

Creating an empty project in Visual Studio Code and adding the code generated by Angular CLI is not the correct way that i got to know so please avoid that. :)

I have implemented it in both the ways i.e. Visual Studio 2017 Project Template and Visual Studio Code. Please let me know if you need any clarification on the same.